# How do I find two intersection points from two parabolas?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, conic-sections

Let's say I have two equations:
$4x+y^2=12$ and $x=y^2-1$

I need to find the two intersection points of these parabolas so I can then calculate the enclosed area. I took a peek at what it would look like on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/02hycaala6).

So if I isolate for the $y$ variable for both equations, I managed to calculate the first intersection which is $(\frac{11}{5}$, $\frac{4}{\sqrt5})$.

How do I calculate the second intersection point? Do I just assume that since the function is a sideways parabola, then the other intersection point would just have a negative $x$ coordinate value?

Comment: $y$ should be $\pm y$

Comment: @MathLover is it because the {y} coordinate is a square root?

Comment: Yes that is correct. If you put $-y$ in both equations, it should give you the same value of $x$ as for $+y$.

Answer (score 1):

1)$y^2=12-4x;$

2)$y^2=x+1;$

Note: Both parabolas are symmetric about $x-$axis.

$12-4x=x+1;$

$x=11/5.$

Points of intersection:

1. $y>0:$ $y=4/\sqrt{5}$, e. g. $P_1(11/5, 4/\sqrt{5})$;
2. $y<0:$ By symmetry $P_2(11/5,-4/\sqrt{5})$.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract one equation from the other, to eliminate y, and solve the resulting equation for x. Both solutions have the same x. Then plug the value of x into either parabola, and solve for y using the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$4(y^2-1)+y^2=12$$ or
$$y^2=\frac{16}{5},$$ which gives $$y=\frac{4}{\sqrt5}$$ or $$y=-\frac{4}{\sqrt5}.$$
Also, $$x=\frac{16}{5}-1$$ or $$x=\frac{11}{5}$$ and we got two intersection points:
$$\left(\frac{11}{5},\frac{4}{\sqrt5}\right)$$ and $$\left(\frac{11}{5},-\frac{4}{\sqrt5}\right)$$